# Zfs send snapshot to different server with different layout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, snapshot

So i am eother missing this use case, or its never come up, or it works fine and i havent treid it yet.

But i have two servers, and i want one to be the backup server of main server.

I moved disks arounds and it looking like main will be raidz1 and backup will be raidz2.

I was wondering if anyone knows if i can send a snapshot from main to backup even though they use different raidz levels.

Thank you in advance for any feedback, or opinion that you may have

has anyone tried this?

Comment: I came across this post when searching for the answer to something - I know zfs used checksums on its raw blocks, including checksum blocks. Does zfs calculate all entirely new checksums when doing a zfs send/recv, or does it somehow use the same ones on the original system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is well within the send/receive parameters. You can send from any layout (stripe, mirror, raidzN) to any other layout.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for clearifying :)
is there something i have to tell it, or will it do it automatically?

Comment: It's all automatic. The "zfs recv" code will write the sent blocks to the new pool with the correct layout. (I could go into great technical detail if you like, but it might get boring)